# How do I split a range of values with commas and "and" before the last value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a code that allows the user to enter a list of items from A1 downwards, and display them all as a list in a sentence with correct commas and 'and' placement.

E.g for the below,

```
 A1. Shoe
 A2. Tree
 A3. Box
 A4. Toy
```

I want a message box to display "You have entered Shoe, Tree, Box and Toy".

I'm completely lost with how to get it to recognise where to put the 'and'.

Any help is appreciated.

I've tried to complete this with some For statements, but I get stuck when identifying where or how to put the 'and' in the list, considering there could be a different number of items in the list.

Thanks

Comment: How are you doing the rest of it? You could write a custom function that does the concatenate bit (probably find one online) and just replace the final comma with 'and'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
Sub Sample()

    ' Define object variables
    Dim listRange As Range
    Dim cellValue As Range

    ' Define other variables
    Dim itemsQuantity As Integer
    Dim stringResult As String
    Dim separator As String
    Dim counter As Integer

    ' Define the range where the options are located
    Set listRange = Range("A1:A4")

    itemsQuantity = listRange.Cells.Count

    counter = 1

    For Each cellValue In listRange

        ' Select the case for inner items, penultimate and last item
        Select Case counter
        Case Is < itemsQuantity
            separator = ", "
        Case Is = itemsQuantity - 1
            separator = " And "
        Case Else
            separator = vbNullString
        End Select

        stringResult = stringResult & cellValue.Value & separator

        counter = counter + 1

    Next cellValue

    ' Assamble the last sentence
    stringResult = "You have entered " & stringResult & "."

    MsgBox stringResult

End Sub
```

Customize the:
' Define the range where the options are located portion

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Your code is quite simple and very easy for me to follow.
I just had to swap the positions of the first and second case, and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

## Column to Sentence

### Features

- At least two cells of data in Range, or else "" is returned.
- Only first column of Range is processed (`Resize`).

### Usage in Excel

[image]

### The Code

```
Function CCE(Range As Range) As String

    Application.Volatile

    Const strFirst = "You have entered "  ' First String
    Const strDEL = ", "                   ' Delimiter
    Const strDELLast = " and "            ' Last Delimiter
    Const strLast = "."                   ' Last String

    Dim vnt1 As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vnt0 As Variant   ' Zero Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Arrays Row Counter

    ' Copy Source Range's first column to 2D 1-based 1-column Source Array.
    vnt1 = Range.Resize(, 1)
    ' Note: Join can be used only on a 0-based 1D array.
    ' Resize Zero Array to hold all data from Source Array.
    ReDim vnt0(UBound(vnt1) - 1)

    ' Copy data from Source Array to Zero Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(vnt1)
        If vnt1(i, 1) = "" Then Exit For
        vnt0(i - 1) = vnt1(i, 1)
    Next

    ' If no "" was found, "i" has to be greater than 3 ensuring that
    ' Source Range contains at least 2 cells.
    If i < 3 Then Exit Function
    ReDim Preserve vnt0(i - 2)

    ' Join data from Zero Array to CCE.
    CCE = Join(vnt0, strDEL)
    ' Replace last occurence of strDEL with strDELLast.
    CCE = WorksheetFunction.Replace( _
            CCE, InStrRev(CCE, strDEL), Len(strDEL), strDELLast)
    ' Add First and Last Strings.
    CCE = strFirst & CCE & strLast

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**Array solution via `Join` with simple transposition**

- Your post assumes a flexible range in column `A:A`, so the first step `[1]` gets the last row number and defines the data range.
- In step `[2]` you assign the found data range to an **array** which has to be variant. The `Application.Transpose` function changes the original column data to a "flat" array in only *one code line* and reduces its 2-dim default dimension to a simple 1-dim array. Furthermore the last element is simply *enriched* by insertion of " and ". This allows you to avoid a complicated split & find action.
- Step `[3]` allows to *concatenate* any 1-dim array via the **`Join`** function and insert any user defined delimiter (e.g. a colon ","). Finally the leading colon before " and" gets deleted by replacing ", and " with " and" only.
- Step `[4]` displays the resulting message box.

**Example code**

```
Option Explicit                               ' declaration head of your code module

Sub displayMsg()
' [0] declare constants and variables
  Const LNK$ = " and ", COLON$ = ","              ' define linking constants "and" plus COLON
  Dim v  As Variant, msg$, lastRow&               ' provide for variant datafield array and message string
  Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range               ' declare worksheet object     *)
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName") ' << change to your sheet name *)
' [1] define flexible range object in column A:A via last row number
  lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)            ' e.g. A1:A4, if n = 4
' [2] get 2-dim column data to "flat" 1-dim array
  v = Application.Transpose(rng)                  ' read into array and make it "flat"
  v(UBound(v)) = LNK & v(UBound(v))               ' insert " and " into last array element
' [3] concatenate elements and delete superfluous last colon
  msg = Replace(Join(v, COLON), COLON & LNK, LNK) ' get wanted message string
' [4] display message
  MsgBox "You have entered " & msg & ".", vbInformation, UBound(v) & " elements"
End Sub
```

**Alternative referencing**

*) Instead of referencing a work sheet `ws` by e.g. `ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("MySheetName")`, you can simply use the worksheet's **CodeName** instead as listed in the VB Editor (without declaring `ws` as well as setting it into the memory) just coding as follows:

```
' [1] define flexible range object in column A:A via last row number
  lastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row  
  Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
```

*Enjoy it* :-)